# Problems with execution after installing Magento2 Open Source to localhost

Tags: installation, localhost

I have the installation of Magento2 Open Source on localhost Windows 10, version 2.4.6 (currently in composer installation)
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/setup/initialization.html?lang=en
made (XAMPP, OpenSearch, everything fresh/up to date), additions and process see below (*).

Unfortunately, access to the standard/admin (/admin_xyz was generated) is not possible.

127.0.0.1 is only assigned to localhost (in hosts).

http://127.0.0.1/magento2 delivers "404", http://127.0.0.1/magento2/pub/ delivers a start page with text, amaong other things "CMS homepage content goes here.", only completely unformatted.

In the console, "Laden fehlgeschlagen für" "http://127.0.0.1/magento2/static/version1700649929/frontend/magento/de_de/mage/requirejs/mixins.js",
"http://127.0.1/magento2/static/version1700649929/frontend/magento/luma/de/requirejsjs-config.js", etc.

The "static" directory is completely missing.

- Process of the installation:

Adjust PHP.ini settings at XAMPP:
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guides/prerequisites/php-settings.html?lang=en
pcre.jit=0
Max_inPut_time=1800
memory_limit=4G
max_execution_time=18000

Username=public key and password=private key are stored.

C:\XAMPP\Apache\Conf\httpd.conf
Loadmodule rewrite_Module modules/mod_rewrite.so activated

Find all Occurrences of *allowoverride none *and change to *allowoverride all *

C:\XAMPP\htdocs\OpenSearch\bin\OpenSearch.bat execute and let them actively (like autostart?)

C:\XAMPP\phpmyadmin\config.inc.php: Password set

Composer Create-Project-Repository-URL=https: //repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community edition C:\XAMPP\htdocs\magento2

## C:\XAMPP\htdocs\Magento2\Vendor\Magento\framework\view\element\template\file\validator.php, line 138:
$ realpath=$ this-> FileDriver-> Trealpath ($ path);

$ realpath=str_replace ('\', '/', $ this-> filedriver-> TroLalpath ($ path));

## C:\XAMPP\htdocs\Magento2\Vendor\Magento\framework\image\adapter\gd2.php, line 96:
if ($ url && iset ($ url ['scheme']) &&! In_array ($ url ['scheme'], $ allowed_schemes)) {
return false;
}

if ($ url && iset ($ url ['scheme']) &&! In_array ($ url ['scheme'], $ allowed_schemes) &&! File_exists ($ filename)) {
return false;
}

php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento2 --db-user=root --db-password=adminxy --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=info@magento3.de --admin-user=admin --admin-password=adminxy --language=de_DE --currency=EUR --timezone=Europe/Berlin --use-rewrites=1 --search-engine=opensearch --opensearch-host=127.0.0.1 --opensearch-port=9200 --opensearch-index-prefix=magento --opensearch-timeout=15

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush

Of course, searched intensively, but no solution, especially for the new version, was found.

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 is not compatible with Windows.

You will have to emulate Linux or Mac on your system.

Comment: Of course it runs in XAMPP

Comment: ok my bad i deeply thought m2 wasn't running with windows without emulating, turns out using werserver can do the trick. Althouch it seems not to be recommended so i guess there might be some issues. I won't be able to help more, sry.